# warning "The GEOS C++ API is unstable, please use the C API instead"

Tags: c++, geos, libgeos

I am trying to develop a small .cpp example in ubuntu using GEOS.
To this end I am trying to build a first example, e.g.
https://github.com/vmx/geos/blob/master/doc/example.cpp

I installed both libgeos++dev and libgeos-dev using synaptics.
This way it finds the .h files and compiles.

However when linking (`-lgeos`), I get:

> warning "The GEOS C++ API is unstable, please use the C API instead"

It seems to me it tries to use the c++ library... Any way to force him to use the correct one and avoid the warning?

Edit:

As noted, this warning is produced when compiling my c++ file, because I have  libgeos++dev and specified `-lgeos` at linking. If I remove  libgeos++dev and leave  libgeos-dev, from the readme, the library asks for e.g.
To compile programs against GEOS:

> ```
>     CFLAGS += -I`geos-config --includes`
>     LDFLAGS += `geos-config --libs`
> ```
>
> Headers:
> #include <geos.h>

This basically means:

```
CFLAGS += -I/usr/include
LDFLAGS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgeos-3.8.0
```

But when I try to compile using e.g.

```
g++ -c -I/usr/include  -o "bfc.o" "bfc.cpp"
```

I get:

```
bfc.cpp:22:10: fatal error: geos.h: No such file or directory
   22 | #include <geos.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
```

(`bfc.cpp` does `#include <geos.h>`)

Comment: That error can only come from *compiling* the source file, probably from one of the header files. It can't be emitted during linking. And you get that because you build a C++ application, with a C++ compiler.

Comment: If you have a new problem, you should really post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the flag to include the C version of GEOS is `-lgeos_c` ...

`-lgeos` always tries to include the C++ version (whether it is installed or not)